# Cordova SVG stroke-dashoffset animation not working

Tags: android, css, cordova, svg

I am having an issue with my svg animation in Cordova (Version 6.0.0) : dashes are not displayed on my Android (the circle is full).

Behavior on my Android 5.0 :

[image]

Behavior on my chrome inspector :

[image]

Here a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3ponxj55/), if you want

Here is the HTML :

```
<svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
</svg>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 187;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    stroke: #4285F4;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    }
}
@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    }
}
```

I have tried to put

- negative value, like : `stroke-dasharray: -187;`
- percent value, like : `stroke-dasharray: 50%;`

but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today, my resolution was to add a second time to the animation. Also added all -webkit prefixes. This second time is the animation delay.

```
#M_x5F_Flow > path {
  stroke-dasharray: 4;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: dash 10s 0s linear;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s 0s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
     stroke-dashoffset : 200;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
     stroke-dashoffset : 200;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

This works on Phonegap Android 5.0, even inside an SVG.